# Dynamically setting the queryset of a ModelMultipleChoiceField to a custom recordset

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've seen all the howtos about how you can set a ModelMultipleChoiceField to use a custom queryset and I've tried them and they work.  However, they all use the same paradigm: the queryset is just a filtered list of the same objects.

In my case, I'm trying to get the admin to draw a multiselect form that instead of using usernames as the text portion of the , I'd like to use the `name` field from my account class.

Here's a breakdown of what I've got:

```
# models.py
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,help_text="A display name that people understand")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True) # Tied to the User class in settings.py

class Organisation(models.Model):
    administrators = models.ManyToManyField(User)


# admin.py
from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class OrganisationAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from ethico.accounts.models import Account
        self.base_fields["administrators"] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=User.objects.all(),
            required=False
        )
        super(OrganisationAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Organisation
```

This works, however, I want `queryset` above to draw a selectbox with the `Account.name` property and the `User.id` property.  This didn't work:

```
queryset=Account.objects.all().order_by("name").values_list("user","name")
```

It failed with this error:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

I figured that this would be easy, but it's turned into hours of dead-ends.  Anyone care to shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom widget, override its `render` method. Here's what I had done for a text field :

```
class UserToAccount(forms.widgets.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if isinstance(value, User) :
            value = Account.objects.get(user=value).name
        return super (UserToAccount, self).render(name, value, attrs=None)
```

Then of course, use the `widget` parameter of your administrator field, in order to use your custom widget.
I don't know if it can be adapted for a `select`, but you can try out.

Answer (score 0):

The queryset needs to be a QuerySet, when you do values_list you get a list so that won't work.

If you want to change the default display of models, just override `__unicode__`. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode

For example:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s for %s" % (self.name, self.user)
```

Django will use `__unicode__` whenever you asks it to print a model. For testing you can just load up a model in the shell and do `print my_instance`.

Comment: I would do exactly that, except that in this case, the model in question is User, which I don't control.  Do you know how I would adjust the __unicode__ property of the User class?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a queue from sebpiq, I managed to figure it out:

```
class OrganisationAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        from django.forms import MultipleChoiceField
        from ethico.accounts.models import Account

        self.base_fields["administrators"] = MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=tuple([(a.user_id, a.name) for a in Account.objects.all().order_by("name")]),
            widget=forms.widgets.SelectMultiple,
            required=False
        )

        super(OrganisationAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Organisation


class OrganisationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrganisationAdminForm


admin.site.register(Organisation, OrganisationAdmin)
```

The key was abandoning the queryset altogether.  Once I went with a fixed `choices=` parameter, everything just worked.  Thanks everyone!